# Using CodeIgniter form_validation rule is_unique with more than one database loaded

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, validation

I have applied the fix to Codeigniter in DB_driver.php to allow me to connect to 2 databases at once by adding `$this->db_select();` to `function simple_query($sql)`.

I then have a MY_Controller.php that loads both my databases and each controller that I have extends it:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->db1 = $this->load->database('db1',TRUE);
    $this->db2 = $this->load->database('db2',TRUE);
  }
}
```

My application is a backend administration panel into for an existing database. I would rather not manipulate the existing database with additional tables, but rather any tables my administration panel needs will be stored in another database (db1 is my panel, db2 is the existing database). My `$active_group` in `/config/database.php` is set to db1.

Form validation in this format:

```
$userRules = "trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[25]|xss_clean|is_unique[users.username]";
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', $userRules);
```

Works just fine because in that case I wish to query the db1 and the users table (my admin panel database).

However, if I want to do the same on db2 with something like this:

```
$useridRules = "trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[25]|xss_clean|is_unique[login.userid]";
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userid', 'Username', $useridRules);
```

Does NOT work because it's still trying to query db1. An error is returned:

```
Error Number: 1146
Table 'db1.login' doesn't exist
SELECT * FROM (`login`) WHERE `user_id` = 'asdfjkl' LIMIT 1
Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
Line Number: 954
```

db1.login definitely doesn't exist, as I need to query db2 for the login table, so the error is expected but not wanted.

I'm curious to see if anyone has found a way to use the is_unique validation rule to query their second database or the first depending on the instance at hand, or if I'll need to write a function using callback instead (or if you think it would be better to simply put my tables into the existing db2 and prefix them with ci_table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a callback function to call a specific function that does the checking:

So change this:

```
$userRules = "trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[25]|xss_clean|is_unique[users.username]";
```

to this:

```
$userRules = "trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[25]|xss_clean|callback_is_unique";
```

you will need to have a function to process it:

```
function is_unique($username){ // $username recieves the parameter automatically
    //Go on with your query as bellow
    $this->db2->
}
```

Comment: I had thought about this but was hoping there was a way I could use the native stuff and not have to write my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just to make this a bit more generic: extend the form validation class, make a new function and use that in the rules.  say your second db is set at $this->db2
your rule would be is_db2_unique[table.field]

In your language file somewhere add the line:
$lang['form_validation_is_db2_unique'] = 'The {field} field must contain a unique value.';

libraries:MY_Form_validation.php

```
<?php if ( defined('BASEPATH') === FALSE ) exit('No direct script access allowed');
// this is used as to extend the base form validation class, 

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{

    function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($rules);
    }

    public function is_db2_unique($str, $field)
    {
        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field);
        return isset($this->CI->db2)
            ? ($this->CI->db2->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;
    }
}
```